# Remove continuous duplicated values with different IDs in MySQL

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I know there is a ton of same questions about finding and removing duplicate values in `mySQL` but my question is a bit different:
I have a table with columns as `ID`, `Timestamp` and `price`. A script scrapes data from another webpage and saves it in the database every 10 seconds. Sometimes data ends up like this:

```
| id | timestamp | price |   
|----|-----------|-------|   
| 1  | 12:13     | 100   |   
| 2  | 12:14     | 120   |   
| 3  | 12:15     | 100   |   
| 4  | 12:16     | 100   |   
| 5  | 12:17     | 110   |
```

As you see there are 3 duplicated values and removing the `price` with `ID = 4` will shrink the table without damaging data integrity. I need to `remove continuous duplicated records except the first one` (which has the lowest `ID` or `Timestamp`).
Is there a sufficient way to do it? (there is about a million records)
I edited my scraping script so it checks for duplicated `price` before adding it but I need to shrink and maintain my old data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MySQL 8.0 you can use window function [LAG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) in next way:

```
delete tbl.* from tbl
join (
    -- use lag(price) for get value from previous row
    select id, lag(price) over (order by id) price from tbl
) l 
-- join rows with same previous price witch will be deleted
on tbl.id = l.id and tbl.price = l.price;
```

[fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=2355400f41f204437ac7a010f0aacb2c&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: Added some explanation

Answer (score 1):

My query is based on @Tim Biegeleisen one.

```
-- delete records
DELETE
FROM yourTable t1
-- where exists an older one with the same price
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.price = t1.price
                    AND t2.id < t1.id
-- but does not exists any between this and the older one
                    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                    FROM yourTable t3
                                    WHERE t1.price <> t3.price
                                          AND t3.id > t2.id
                                          AND t3 < t1.id));
```

It deletes records where exists an older one with same price but does not exists any different between

It could be checked by `timestamp` column if `id` column is not numeric and ascending.

Comment: Thanks for great answer but I'm having a hard time executing it. It gives me error 1064.

Comment: The error was caused by bad comment (missing space)

Answer (score 1):

I am just grouping based on price and filtering only one record per group.The lowest id gets displayed.Hope the below helps.

```
 select id,timestamp,price from yourTable group by price having count(price)>0;
```